# How to open a source file in a project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-extensions

I am trying to open a file in an open project in Visual Studio using the extension API. I found this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb164729(v=vs.110).aspx

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsuishellopendocument.openstandardeditor(v=vs.110).aspx

but I don't understand how to implement it. Is there any guide for it or am I looking in the wrong place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look here:

- [DTE.OpenFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte._dte.openfile.aspx)
- [DTE.ItemOperations.OpenFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.itemoperations.openfile%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Usage:

```
DTE.ExecuteCommand("File.OpenFile", @"C:\path\to\source_file.cs");
```

---

TIP:
To test the method open [VS Command Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/c785s0kz.aspx) and simply type `File.OpenFile`

Comment: Thanks, rather than an absolute path to source, can I do relative path within the current solution/project?